# Java FutureOrPresent validation implementation not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I'm working on an implementation for `FutureOrPresent` validator for type `Long`.

```
public class FutureOrPresentValidatorForLong implements ConstraintValidator<FutureOrPresent, Long> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        final long now = new Date().getTime();
        return value >= now;
    }
}
```

However, when trying to send a request, the following issue happens:

> No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.FutureOrPresent' validating type 'java.lang.Long

Any ideas what went wrong?